# MAMP & Command Line -- Changing PATH to use MAMP

Tags: command-line, mamp

I have a question on how to make my Terminal command line interface on Mac to use MAMP's PHP and MySQL instead of what's already installed on my machine.  I created a new file in my home directory called .bash_profile and I added this:

```
PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin:\
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Now when I type "which mysql" is shows correctly that it's using MAMP.  But when I try "which php" it's still using the pre-installed Mac version.  Any idea on how I can get it to use MAMP instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `hash -d php` to tell bash to forget the location of the `php` binary.

Comment: It seems to pickup the same original PHP location again each time I start Terminal.